# MySQL Service Stop although Restart=Always

Tags: centos7, mariadb, mysql5.5, webmin

I've an Amazon t2.small EC2 - **1 Core and 2GB RAM** it's more than the minimum requirements for CentOS and Virtualmin

My System:

- CentOS 7.5.1804
- Virtualmin
- MySQL 5.5.60-MariaDB
- Apache 2.4.6

The MySQL service was always stop working a month ago after a lot of visits and I can restart it from Webmin again until I read an article in DigitalOcean blog to add the [**Restart=Always**] in the file [**/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mariadb.service**] and I test it by killing the process then the service starts again automatically **No stop for 22 days**

Now the service stopped working again, I opened the [mariadb.service] file I found the line [Restart=Always] still there but the service stopped randomly.

Note: I still can start it from the Webmin no problem with that, But all websites become unavailable because of DB connection.

I need to trace this issue but I've no experience for such issues .. How to solve that?

MySQL configuration: **my.conf**

```
symbolic-links=0
innodb_file_per_table = 1
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
sort_buffer_size = 512K
table_open_cache = 64
max_allowed_packet = 1M
key_buffer_size = 16M
```

Some lines from {**var/log/messages**}

```
Oct 22 16:49:49 ns1 kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 13092 (mysqld) score 97 or sacrifice child

Oct 22 16:49:49 ns1 kernel: Killed process 13092 (mysqld) total-vm:1065992kB, anon-rss:182972kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB

Oct 22 16:49:49 ns1 kernel: [12822]    27 12822    28326       73      14        0             0 mysqld_safe


Oct 23 08:58:11 ns1 kernel: [12822]    27 12822    28326       74      14        0             0 mysqld_safe
Oct 23 08:58:11 ns1 kernel: [19703]    27 19703   266425    39874     150        0             0 mysqld

Oct 23 20:04:47 ns1 saslauthd[531]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=mysql] [service=smtp] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]

Oct 23 22:21:25 ns1 kernel: [12822]    27 12822    28326       74      14        0             0 mysqld_safe
Oct 23 22:21:25 ns1 kernel: [19703]    27 19703   266425    48494     161        0             0 mysqld
Oct 23 22:21:25 ns1 kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 19703 (mysqld) score 103 or sacrifice child
Oct 23 22:21:25 ns1 kernel: Killed process 19703 (mysqld) total-vm:1065700kB, anon-rss:193976kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Oct 23 22:21:25 ns1 kernel: [12822]    27 12822    28326       74      14        0             0 mysqld_safe
Oct 23 22:39:58 ns1 kernel: [12822]    27 12822    28326       76      14        0             0 mysqld_safe
Oct 23 22:39:58 ns1 kernel: [19246]    27 19246   266716    16891      98        0             0 mysqld
Oct 23 22:40:02 ns1 kernel: [12822]    27 12822    28326       76      14        0             0 mysqld_safe
Oct 23 22:40:02 ns1 kernel: [19246]    27 19246   266938    17064      98        0             0 mysqld
Oct 23 22:40:05 ns1 kernel: mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Oct 23 22:40:05 ns1 kernel: mysqld cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Oct 23 22:40:05 ns1 kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 19357 Comm: mysqld Kdump: loaded Not tainted 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 #1
```

Comment: Have you looked at the mysql logs after it shuts down to see WHY it shut down?

Comment: MySQL crashed because it ran out of memory. Run mysqltuner.pl and check its memory recommendations.

Comment: I've add some lines of error log to the question .. I saw some (do_auth) before (Out of memory) message .. maybe it's related?? I don't know .. but I made a lot of visits and load a lot of pages 300 pages and the service working properly

Comment: Actually it's the system that ran out of memory. That's why you see `Out of memory: Kill process 13092`, the system decided to kill your MySQL process to free some memory and survive.

Comment: So what should I do? the next level of EC2 t2.medium is doubled price :) :)

Comment: I would say it depends what is running on the server, and what kind of tuning has been done already.

Comment: I saw the mysqltuner.pl but I didn't run such tuners for mysql or apache before

Comment: I review another mysql conf on DigitalOcean droplet (1GB RAM) I noticed that {key_buffer_size} is 16K while my conf is 16M .. is 16M too much??

Comment: Configuring MySQL properly is an other topic @HadyShaltout.

Comment: I understand from @MichaelHampton that mysqltuner.pl could help

Comment: Hey guys .. Could spam mails do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution after 12 days of testing the MySQL start after killed  automatically with hundreds of page visits.

**The answer depends on the question System OS (CentOS) and MySQL Mariadb service**

**Solution:** Just add some seconds before make service start - in my case I've added 45 seconds

Add the following lines under [service] section in {**/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mariadb.service**} - Of course the path depends on your system OS and MySQL service name (not all have mariadb.service)

```
Restart=always
RestartSec=45s
```

Do NOT forget to run the following commands

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl restart mariadb.service
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea. I would start with a tout of the usual suspects

- check the diskspace status just to be safe
  *df -h*
  and the memory
  *free -m*
  *uptime* (to check just after a crash)
- check that the ownership and rights have not been changed on the data directories

Answer (score 0):

From this line in your log output :
`Oct 22 16:49:49 ns1 kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 13092 (mysqld) score 97 or sacrifice child`

One can tell that your systemd did ran out of memory and that the Linux OOM (Out of memory) killer did stop your mysqld(MySQL daemon) process.

From the description of [Restart=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=) section, it's written that it won't restart if `the service is stopped with systemctl stop or an equivalent operation`, and maybe OOM killer is an equivalent for systemd, that I don't know.

### Dangerous section

It seems that you can [disable OOM killing](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#OOMScoreAdjust=) for your process, by adding `OOMScoreAdjust=-1000` to disable this functionnality.

Comment: You're right bro, That's too dangerous